# Vaadin combo opens to wrong direction

Tags: vaadin

The affected combo is located near bottom of the browser window.
I would assume that the drop down list is opened on top, but it is not.
Bug?
Related to styling of the containing DIVs?
Or is there any possibility to force displaying the drop down list above?

[Link to screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Bym.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

bug in vaadin, submitted to their git

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).